# Unity Soft Shadows

Tags: unity, lighting, shadows

I'm building a puzzle level in Unity. I have a ball with cracks on it and a point light inside it. The goal is to project the light coming through the cracks into the walls.

I've managed to do that but the lighting isn't soft (it doesn't scatter on the surface, so it looks very sharp). The walls are simple Unity cubes.

[image: Soft shadows]

I'm using 'Soft Shadows' on the light's properties but that doesn't seem to make a diference. My guess is that the occluder is so close to the light source that the lighting becames very sharp. Is there a way to control its softness?

I've tried messing with the smoothness of the wall's material but it didn't make a difference.

I've also tried making the cracks into an albedo map with alpha channel (with null or close-to-null alpha values where I wanted the cracks) and the ball a perfect sphere instead of the ball's mesh having physical cracks. Although it works with cutoff mode, it gives me the same result as before. Another thing I tried was to set it to transparent mode, but the transparent shadows are terrible! Is there a way to improve their quality?

I've searched for (free) Soft Shadow Assets for point lights but couldn't find any.

Is there a solution for this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't with the shadows / materials but with the light itself? In blender and in real life, bigger light source == soft shadows. Can you adjust lights "areaSize"?

Comment: @lilKriT Your thought makes sense but I'm using a point light, and point lights don't have an area size. I can't change it to any other light type either.

Comment: I see. Have you seen this document?
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ShadowOverview.html

Under "enabling shadows" you can choose hard vs soft shadows. Can you use that?

Comment: @lilKriT Yes, I said I was using 'Soft shadows' on the light's properties.

Comment: That's a thread I found on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41811685/unity-real-time-soft-shadow
Maybe this will help?

Comment: You can also improve the softness of point light shadows [using the shader change described here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/soft-shadows-for-point-lights-my-implementation.375949/)

Comment: @lilKriT Yes, I saw that post before, it was already set to that option.

Comment: @DMGregory I tried it, it didn't work at all

Comment: The last thing I can think of is scale of the game itself. Maybe if you make the objects bigger or smaller, the shadows will become softer?